# Wrapping multiple sequences of list elements using XSL transformation (XML to XML)

Tags: xml, xslt, transformation

I have some input long (about 3k lines) XML document, which generally looks as:

```
<chapter someAttributes="someValues">
    <title>someTitle</title>

    <p>multiple paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <li>
        <p>- some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>- some other text</p>
    </li>
    <!-- another li elements -->

    <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <li>
        <p>1. some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>2. some other text</p>
    </li>
    <!-- another li elements -->

    <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <!-- there are other elements such as table, illustration, ul etc. -->  
</chapter>
```

What I want is to wrap **every** scattered (I mean between paragraphs, tables, illustrations etc.) **sequence** of `li` elements with `ol` or `ul` element depending on some semantic and return wrapped XML.

- if first character in paragraph is equal to `-`, then it should be `ul` with `mark="DASH"` attribute
- if paragraphs starts with `1.`, `2.`, `3.` etc, then I want `ol` with `numeration="ARABIC"`

For example (it's just one sequence):

```
<ul mark="DASH">
    <li>
        <p> some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p> some other text</p>
    </li>
<ul>
```

As you see furthermore I need to **cut** "mark character(s)" from all paragraphs, that is `-` or `1.`, `2.`, `3.` etc.

That input XML is more complicated than I described (nested sequences, inner sequences in table elements), but I am looking for some idea, especially how to *catch & process* particular sequence with such semantic.

I want output XML with exactly same ordering, just with wrapped `li` elements. XSLT 2.0/EXSLT are available if needed.

Comment: Szpetkowski: I know you already have accepted the answer, and probably you are happy with that. However it was challenging for me provide a fully _functional_ answer (no loops, conditionals). I've edited my answer so that now it is as I was wondering. Cheers

Comment: @empo: Thank you for your effort, both approaches works great for me.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an XSLT 2.0 stylesheet:

```
<xsl:stylesheet
  xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
  version="2.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:apply-templates select="@*, node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="chapter">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="*" group-adjacent="boolean(self::li)">
        <xsl:choose>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and ./p[1][starts-with(., '-')]">
            <ul mark="DASH">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </ul>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:when test="current-grouping-key() and ./p[1][matches(., '[0-9]\.')]">
            <ol numeration="arabic">
              <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
            </ol>
          </xsl:when>
          <xsl:otherwise>
            <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
          </xsl:otherwise>
        </xsl:choose>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>

  <xsl:template match="li/p/text()[1]">
    <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^(-|[0-9]\.)', '')"/>
  </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

When I use Saxon 9.3 with that stylesheet and the sample input

```
<chapter someAttributes="someValues">
    <title>someTitle</title>

    <p>multiple paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <li>
        <p>- some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>- some other text</p>
    </li>
    <!-- another li elements -->

    <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <li>
        <p>1. some text</p>
    </li>
    <li>
        <p>2. some other text</p>
    </li>
    <!-- another li elements -->

    <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
    <p>...</p>

    <!-- there are other elements such as table, illustration, ul etc. -->  
</chapter>
```

I get the following output:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<chapter>
   <title>someTitle</title>
   <p>multiple paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul mark="DASH">
      <li>
        <p> some text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p> some other text</p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <ol numeration="arabic">
      <li>
        <p> some text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
        <p> some other text</p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
</chapter>
```

Comment: +1. I'd like to get the same solution without `xsl:for-each-group` either.

Comment: Why? Is this some kind of personal challenge, like climbing Everest without use of oxygen, or is there some technical reason for avoiding the very construct which makes the problem easy to solve?

Comment: @Michael-Kay: I don't know, but it seems like your opinion [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196271/conditional-statements-in-xslt-when-having-to-choose-a-tag-from-several-elements)

Comment: Honnen: as you can see, I hope, there was no any intent to discredit your answer (which was selected as the best all the time).

Answer (score 1):

Here's a full *functional* solution, without any procedural approach like `xsl:for-each-group` and `xsl:if`.

**XSLT 2.0** tested under **Saxon-B 9.0.0.1J**

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" version="2.0">
    <xsl:output indent="yes" method="html"/>

    <xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

    <!-- identity -->
    <xsl:template match="node()|@*">
        <xsl:copy>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="node()|@*"/>
        </xsl:copy>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- override dash list elements -->
    <xsl:template match="li[(name(preceding-sibling::*[position()=1]) 
        != name(current())) 
        and matches(.,'^-')]">

        <ul mark="DASH">
            <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
            <!-- apply recursive template for adjacent nodes -->
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()
                =name(current())]" mode="next"/>
        </ul>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- override numeration list elements -->
    <xsl:template match="li[(name(preceding-sibling::*[position()=1]) 
        != name(current())) 
        and matches(.,'^[0-9]\.')]">
        <ol numeration="ARABIC">
            <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
            <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()
                =name(current())]" mode="next"/>
        </ol>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- recursive template for adjacent nodes -->
    <xsl:template match="*" mode="next">
        <li><xsl:apply-templates/></li>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="following-sibling::*[1][name()
            =name(current())]" mode="next"/>
    </xsl:template>

    <!-- remove marks/numeration from first text node -->
    <xsl:template match="li/p/text()[1]">
        <xsl:value-of select="replace(., '^(-|[0-9]\.)\s+', '')"/>
    </xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Applied on your input produces:

```
<chapter someAttributes="someValues">
   <title>someTitle</title>
   <p>multiple paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <ul mark="DASH">
      <li>
         <p>some text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <p>some other text</p>
      </li>
   </ul>
   <!-- another li elements -->
   <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <ol numeration="ARABIC">
      <li>
         <p>some text</p>
      </li>
      <li>
         <p>some other text</p>
      </li>
   </ol>
   <!-- another li elements -->
   <p>multiple other paragraphs</p>
   <p>...</p>
   <!-- there are other elements such as table, illustration, ul etc. -->
</chapter>
```

Comment: There is nothing remotely procedural about xsl:for-each-group or xsl:choose. I don't think your solution here is in any way superior to the one using xsl:for-each-group: what qualities do you think it has that makes it superior?

Comment: @Michael-Kay: I'm not saying my (humble) solution is superior. Please sorry if you get such a opinion. Now I'm really interested in this point, as I read such a kind of comments from you directly and other people. For example see [your answer here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6196271/conditional-statements-in-xslt-when-having-to-choose-a-tag-from-several-elements#answer-6198453). If I have misunderstood things please clarify to me.